# How do I fix "in '+': no implicit conversion from Integer to String"?

Tags: ruby, notepad++

New user here, so I apologise if this post wasn't formatted correctly.

I am learning how to write Ruby, and I'm using Notepad++. One of the files I'm working on is *todemu.rb*, which is a file that *tells you details about a character* called Todemu.

One of the methods I added was:

```rb
todemu.age = "27"
```

to show the age. Then, I put that into a variable so it'd be easier for me to insert that in a sentence.

```rb
x = todemu.age
puts "How old is Todemu?"
puts "Todemu is" + " " + x.to_s + " " + "years old."
```

which displays the output I wanted, *Todemu is 27 years old.*

Then, I tried to increase the value of the age by using this bit of code:

```rb
x += 1
```

Yet, the console in Notepad++ (I used the *NppExec* plugin for this) showed this error:
`todemudan.rb:26:in '+': No implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)`

Why does it show the **plus** sign in the error, and how do I fix this?

Also, I have looked into most of the similarly worded questions in Stack Overflow, but none seem to rectify my problem (*thanks iGian for reminding me*).

Thanks in advance, and I apologise for the length of the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356609/ruby-no-implicit-conversion-of-fixnum-into-string-typeerror)

Comment: It might seem as a duplicate, but the reason I asked is because I have looked into the questions, and none seem to help me rectify my problem at all. Anyway, I'll put this into the question. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: `x.to_s` is superfluous :)

Comment: In some languages types are implicitly converted when performing an operation. The Ruby error is telling you that this does not occur here, so you need to explicitly convert i.e. do it manually before addition.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that I became stupid and made `todemu.age` a String instead of an Integer. Thanks for the help, iGian & Sagar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep the age in a String and are trying to apply the “+” operator with an Integer. You should probably store the age as an Integer so you can add to it using “+”. If that is not possible you can always cast using .to_i before adding, eg:

```
age = x.to_i+1
```

I’d suggest going through some tutorials that cover Ruby’s type system, for instance: http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/datatypes/

Ruby's type system forces you to mind your types in such cases rather than for instance PHP's + operator which will concatenate if one of the parameters is a string and the other an integer (without throwing an error)

Integer adding

```
i = 1
i + 1 # => 2
```

String + Integer

```
i = "1"
i + 1 # => error
i.to_i + 1 # => 2
i + "1" # => 11
```

Interpolation

```
i = 27
puts "My age is #{i}" # => My age is 27
```

Comment: Also you might want to try Sublime or Atom with Ruby plugins or Rubymine rather than Notepad++

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick reply! After reading this, I quickly facepalmed myself for forgetting that the `x` is a String. 

Anyway, I converted it first by using `x.to_i`, then I ran this: `x += 1`. It _still gives the same error_. Am I doing something wrong here?

Also, I have considered Sublime and Atom, but I read that Atom is slow, and Sublime is a bit pestering. Is it better for me to switch or not?

Comment: If you want to use x+=1 to increase x's value you should create it as an integer in the first place. puts x.to_i+1 will work though if x is a string. I recommend creating x as an integer in the first place as it will eliminate a lot of potential for confusion.

Comment: Oh my god. That's the solution! I should've made the age an Integer instead of a String! After changing from `todemu.age = "27"` to `todemu.age = 27`, the code works as intended. Thank you so much!

Comment: `x.to_i` does not *convert* x to an Integer. The value stored in x does not change. The `to_i` method returns an Integer corresponding to the value stored in `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.to_i` method on the string which represents number. `.to_i` will coerce the string to integer and `.to_f` will convert it as float. But make sure string represents number. If you call `'number'.to_i` it will return zero